# Reprogramming Makerbot Extruder Controller 3.6 with Arduino toolchain?

Tags: extruder, makerbot

Long story, but I inherited a friend's old experimental Replicator project (version 1, balsa frame), which included a bunch of Makerbot EC3 extruder controllers.

After scrounging around the net for old documentation, I found a few threads suggesting these things can be reprogrammed. I'm on a budget, and the ability to control high-current applications straight from an Arduino interface would be pretty neat. Once firmware exists, there's a procedure to flash it, but I'm interested in something a little more straightforward. Someone in the forums said that these can be programmed from the Arduino IDE (as the boards are Arduino derivatives), but I haven't found any official documentation on the subject.

(1) Does anyone know if it's possible to reprogram these straight from the Arduino IDE?

(2) Is there a known conversion between board pins and extruder controller pins?

Links I found:

[1] https://github.com/makerbot/G3Firmware

[2] http://makerbot.wikidot.com/ec36-firmware-installation

[3] https://www.reprap.me/makerbot-extruder.html

[4] http://web.archive.org/web/20110905083750/http://wiki.makerbot.com/thingomatic-doc:extruder-controller-3-6

[5] http://makerbot.wikidot.com/forum/t-367035/flashing-extruder-controller-3-6

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: OK, just found this link (for an older product) - will try and see if this version is similar.

http://www.geeetech.com/wiki/index.php/Extruder_Controller_2.2